# Power BI user input autocomplete text field

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have address records with civic,streetname,town and other data with other tables linked to it.

Is there a way in PowerBI to have a user input text box(string) that the user can type in that will filter records containing a match to that string which they could then drill through to get more information?

IE:

```
4 Smith Street Blackville
5 Main Street Blackville
10 Smith Street Greenville
```

If the user types Black they get the first 2 records, if they type ville they get all 3 records?

I have looked at slicers/paramaters but cannot figure it out?

Thanks

Comment: There are some custom Search box in the app store you can give a try with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Text Filter](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104381309) custom visual could help you with that. It provides a search box that can be used to filter all other visuals on your dashboard with a text contains search on the field you specify.

[image]

To import a Power BI visual, in the `Visualization` pane click `Import a custom visual` and select `Import from file`. Then select the `.pbiviz` file downloaded from the store.

Comment: This filter does not autocomplete